# How to configure openapi.yaml to select one of responses of CSV or JSON type for same status code?

Tags: openapi

I am trying to implement a feature which asks the user based on what format they want certain report to be downloaded - CSV or JSON? Based on this feature, I am trying to configure my `openapi.yaml` (version 3) to send one of responses for status code 200 as shown below:

```yaml
      responses:
        "200":
          description: returns download report successfully
          oneOf:
            - content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    items:
                      type: array
                      items:
                        $ref: "#/components/schemas/ReportResponse"
            - content:
                text/csv: {}
```

But I am running into `Schema validation: Property 'oneOf' is not allowed`  error.

I tried looking up for solution, but I could not find any. I have seen examples where for `application/json` I can select one of multiple schemas, but I want the content type itself be different depending on user request.

Am I doing something wrong here? If this is not possible, are there any workarounds to achieve this?

Comment: It's implicit that the API is only going to return one response. Get rid of the `oneOf` and just list multiple response types under `content`. See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @blueteeth explained in the comments, you don't need `oneOf` here. Instead, list all the media types under the `content` key:

```yaml
      responses:
        "200":
          description: returns download report successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  items:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: "#/components/schemas/ReportResponse"
            text/csv: {}
```

Comment: I assume you meant to include a "don't" in of "you need `oneOf`"